# Move the window while having a custom title bar and it not snapping to the corner of the cursor

Tags: python, tkinter

Can anyone help me figure out how to move the window and it not snapping to the corner while using a custom title bar...

```
from tkinter import *


root = Tk()
root.geometry('571x819')
root.overrideredirect(1)
root.wm_attributes("-transparentcolor", "grey")

def move_app(e):
      root.geometry(f'+{e.x_root}+{e.y_root}')

frame_photo = PhotoImage(file = 'F:\\gui\\Frame 1.png')
frame_label = Label(root, borderwidth = 0, bg = 'grey', image = frame_photo)
frame_label.pack(fill=BOTH, expand = True)

title_bar = Frame(root, bg='#FFF6C9', relief='raised', bd=0,highlightthickness=0)
title_bar_title = Label(title_bar, bg='#FFF6C9',bd=0,fg='white',font=("helvetica", 
10),highlightthickness=0)
frame_label.bind("<B1-Motion>", move_app)




root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can save the offset from the top-left corner of window when start moving by binding the `<Button-1>` event, then calculate the position the top-left corner of the window based on this offset inside `move_app()`:

```py
def start_drag(e):
    # save the offset from the top-left corner of window
    e.widget.offset = (e.x, e.y)

def move_app(e):
    # calculate the top-left corner of window based on the saved offset
    root.geometry(f'+{e.x_root-e.widget.offset[0]}+{e.y_root-e.widget.offset[1]}')

...

frame_label.bind("<Button-1>", start_drag)
frame_label.bind("<B1-Motion>", move_app)

...
```